# getElementById is not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my application i just want to alert the value in the text box using javascript .

aspx page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hi");
        alert(document.getElementById('<%=textbox1.ClientID%>').value);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="textbox1"  Text="asdsad">
            </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I only get alert 'hi' ..after that i get an error " object required" . whats the reason?

Comment: why i got a down vote? ..please comment..so that i can improve that in my next post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is running before the element has been displayed on the screen. Try -

```
window.onload = function() {
     alert("hi");
     alert(document.getElementById('<%=textbox1.ClientID%>').value);
}
```

Or move your script to the bottom of the page as suggested by Tejs in the comments below.

Comment: Basically this. The script in your head element runs before the body has loaded. The easiest way to do this is to move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @ipr101 Thanks a bunch good sir.  This was the headache for me for quite some time today!

Answer (score 1):

The page is not loaded yet.  You have to put the code in a function and then trigger with

onload=yourfunction;

Answer (score 1):

Please change the script location, put the script code on bottom of the page.Just After the complete with form tag.

Answer (score 1):

The ID you are trying to get is a server side id and not the html id of the element, if you checked using firebug you will notice that the id has loads of extra letters and numbers inserted by asp.net, i'd recommend using jquery instead to walk into the dom to select the specific element.

You could also add a name and getByName.